# Which urls to avoid caching for Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, service-worker

I'm using the service worker made by the angular-cli. It has a config file (ngsw-config.json), where you can define urls to preferably be fetched from the network, instead of the worker's cache.

As I understand it, angularfire (and the plain JS firestore libraries), use websockets when available, which can't get cached. In case that they are not available, the library probably falls back to http polling. If I do not set the service worker to forward those http requests to firebase, I guess that data could get out of sync.

I could not find any documentation on the subject.

I'm guessing that setting `*.google.com/**` to `freshness` strategy, would suffice, but 1) I'm not sure, 2) I'd rather whitelist something more specific.

PS I have found [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls), but it's not about firestore or rtdb